# Modem Network Disconnected

Tags: ubuntu, networking, internet, modem, sim

I have Ubuntu 12.10 operating system on my laptop and I use a Reliance 3G modem (ZTE MF 190). When I use Tata Docomo sim to connect to the internet, it seldom gets connected and after some time it automatically gets disconnected. Once it gets disconnected, it becomes unable to connect again, whatever I do (like re-inserting the modem, restarting the computer etc). After getting disconnected, the modem seems to initialize again (as the necessary connection information like names of the mobile broadband connections etc. disappear in the network menu on the top-right corner and then appear again). This continues as I keep clicking on "Tata Docomo 1" (configuration name) to connect to the internet. It only says, "Modem network disconnected, you are now offline". I think there is no problem with the configuration as I am always prompted to set it. On windows operating system also, the connection gets disconnected automatically, but it is possible to connect again after some trials. This problem does not occur in case of other connections like Vodafone, Aircel, Reliance etc. One thing I should mention that all these connections except Tata Docomo are considered as "home network", but for Tata Docomo, it says "You are registered on a roaming network". Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Type this into the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modemswitch.rules
```

Now locate:

```
# ZTE MF190

ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1542", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Add # before the ATTRS, like this

```
# ZTE MF190J

#ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1542", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

reboot, DONE.